# What is the correct way to pass an Rx Observable inside the program?

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I have a rather strange question about passing the Observables and subscription inside the app. Most of the examples are showing tightly coupled code, which is not really what one want.

The question is quite general, but I am using WPF with MVVM framework.

Let's say I have something like this:

[image: example]

Right now it is done with events and on every event Classes are filtered by ID and action is taken by the method call on found class.

I am thinking about replacing event with Rx.

Subject is a stream of events (hot) and sending data all the time. Class 1,2, etc are subscribed and act on UI (for example).

Most example like [Replacing C# Events](https://rehansaeed.com/reactive-extensions-part1-replacing-events/) are using IDisposable and I will need it in every component.

```
private IDisposable planeSpottedSubscription;
jetfighter.PlaneSpotted.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, “Eurofighter”)).Subscribe(this.OnPlaneSpotted);
```

But, I can't subscribe to everything from Main, because it doesn't know about all components in UserControls and items are added dynamically (Class3, Class4 of MyType). Subscribing a Facade is not a problem.

So the question sound like:

Should I pass `IObservable<JetFighter>` to every control (line in ctor) and make a subscription to `IDisposable` (sounds strange) or can I somehow reuse Observable and just add filters?

Comment: You can't make subscriptions to `IDisposable`. Can you please clarify what you mean?